# Checking to see if blob is still needed

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a site where I store files for different users, users can add and delete files as they want.  Within a User object on the datastore I'll have an array of blobstore keys for their files.

If I want to periodically check to make sure all my blobs are still being pointed to by a key stored in one of the User objects, is there an easy way to do that rather than do a query on the users for each blobstore key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to do this other than yourself manually.

You can probably write a mapreduce if you have a very large dataset, otherwise you should maintain when a blob is no longer required in your application logic.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this was the answer.